# How to export a dataframe to excel with sheets based on values in a column

Tags: python, export-to-excel

I have created a data frame in Python based on marging multiple excel files, and now I would like to export that combined data to one .xlsx file with multiple sheets based on values in a column and have those sheets named after the value in the column.

using examples from the images below, I can currently export all the data to an .xlsx file.

What I would like to do is filter the data by the zone column, and export all the data associated with the Zone1 flag in the Zone column to a sheet named "Zone1" and all the data associated with the flag Zone2 to a sheet named "Zone2" . Ideally, in the second image, the highlighted data is the only data what would show up in the current "Zone1" Sheet, and the unhighlighted data would be in sheet "Zone2"

I'm using the following code to pull in the data, merge, and export.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob

glob.glob("/Users/xxx/Desktop/PythonTests/Test_Zone*.xlsx")

all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in     glob.glob("/Users/xxx/Desktop/PythonTests/Test_Zone*.xlsx"):
df = pd.read_excel(f)
all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)
all_data.to_excel("/Users/xxx/Desktop/merged.xlsx",index=False)
```

[image: What I currently can export]

[image: What I'd like to export]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a dataframe, `df`, that holds all of your data (if you have it already saved as an excel file, you can just use `df = pd.read_excel('path_to_file.xlsx')`), you can use the following code to subset your dataframe by `Zone` and save each resultant subsetted dataframe to the dictionary `df_dict`:

```
df_dict = {}

for zone in df['Zone'].unique():
    zone_df = df[df['Zone'] == zone]
    df_dict[zone] = zone_df
```

Once you have this dictionary, you can use `pd.ExcelWriter` and `to_excel` to write your dataframes into separate sheets of an excel file:

```
def save_xlsx(df_dict, path):
    """
    Save a dictionary of dataframes to an excel file, with each dataframe as a seperate page
    """

    with pd.ExcelWriter(path) as writer:
        for key in df_dict:
            df_dict[key].to_excel(writer, key, index=False)

    writer.save()
```

Calling the function will give you your desired result:

```
save_xlsx(df_dict, 'path_to_file.xlsx')
```

If you wanted to take out the spaces in your sheet names (as you have done in your example) you can modify the `save_xlsx` function accordingly:

```
df_dict[key].to_excel(writer, key.replace(' ',''), index=False)
```

Comment: I tried out your code to use a already combined excel file, and after my code to combine files. Using an already created excel file that had all the combined data worked great, thanks!! I then tried to use the code right after my original code to combine files, and somehow I'm only exporting an excel file with a sheet named "Zone 2" (and it's correct data), but not the previous Sheet for "Zone1." I will add the code I tried in the answers section

Comment: This was very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I tried that only exported Zone2 rather than 1 and 2"

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob

#list
glob.glob("/Users/TTT/Desktop/PythonTests/Test_Zone*.xlsx")

ALLDATA = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("/Users/TTT/Desktop/PythonTests/Test_Zone*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    ALLDATA = ALLDATA.append(df,ignore_index=True)

    df_dict = {}

for zone in df['Zone'].unique():
    zone_df = df[df['Zone'] == zone]
    df_dict[zone] = zone_df

save_xlsx(df_dict, '/Users/TTT/Desktop/PythonTests/ExportTest.xlsx')
```